# Can TS recognise Record keys might be undefined?

Tags: typescript

If I define a type:

```
type MyType = Record<string, SubType>;

const myObject = { key: value };
```

Then every time I access a property on `myObject`, TypeScript assumes that the type is `SubType`. This quite clearly isn't the case as there's no way that any object will ever have a value for *EVERY* possible key. This leads to uncaught undefined values.

My question is this:

**Is there an optimal way to ensure that TypeScript identifies that a value may be undefined if the key doesn't exist?**

I know that you can either specify the keys

```
type MyKeys = 'key';
type MyType = Record<MyKeys, SubType>;
```

(which isn't always possible as in some cases they are only set at runtime), or I could create my own generic that specifically says that the value might be `undefined`, but it feels like either TypeScript should do this automatically for objects keyed with `string` or have some other built-in way of doing it.

Comment: can't you just do this:  `type MyType = Record<MyKeys, SubType | undefined>;` ?

Comment: I can, but it seems long-winded to do that every time I define a type.
Plus, if you specify keys explicitly TS doesn't let you access anything not in `MyKeys`, so thats not a problem. 
 My issue is that almost by definition I want `Record<string, something>` to know that when I access a key it might be `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using nodejs with `@types/node`, there is a type [`NodeJS.Dict<T>`](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules__types_node_globals_d_.nodejs.dict.html) which supports undefined, but I cannot find any example usage about it, maybe the `NodeJS` namespace is not preferred to be used directly.

Anyway, you can simply define your own utility type, which can also be used outside nodejs.

```
interface Dict<T> {
    [key: string]: T | undefined;
}
```

Comment: This is essentially the second way I describe in my question, which i was hoping there'd be an alternative to

Comment: Okay than the answer is no because the type package is also defining Dict<T> by itself.